# (C#) How to open a file in my program via drag and "Open with ..."

Tags: c#, forms

Windows has a feature where you can drag a file onto a program or shortcut and it will say "Open with (program name)" I want to be able to do this for my program and when I open with a file be able to go to the text editor portion of my program.

```
string filePath = //Find path of file just opened
form_editScript edit = new form_editScript(filePath);
edit.Show();
Hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle the "Open with..." you will need to get the file path from the `args` of `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = args.FirstOrDefault();
    ....
    Application.Run(new form_editScript(filePath))
```

For the Drag-Drop part you will have to set the form's `AllowDrop` property to `true` then subscribe to `DragEnter` and `DragDrop` events. In the `DragEnter` check if the `Data` is a file then allow the drop. In the `DragDrop` you will get string array with the files being dropped:

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = ((string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop))[0];
    ....
```

Comment: Does this code make it so you are able to drag files into the window? If so, I'll still use it because I need this too, but I was asking if you drag a file onto a program on your desktop or in file explorer or something.

Comment: The first part of my answer will let you handle this case. The second part deals with drag-drop into an already opened application.

Comment: Idiot me, could have just used an if statement. All working now, thanks for the help